# serve package from npm didn't work with React

Tags: reactjs, serve

I want to try the serve package with a React App by doing the following step:

npm install serve --s

then replace the npm start command  in package.json like this:

```
  scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    ...
  },
```

and then I run npm start i got the error in the console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" etc

however if I uninstall serve --s and put back the package.json like this :

```
  scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    ...
  },
```

and then run npm start again it work fine on my local machine, so i think i am doing something wrong in the process and i would like to know why I have issue with the serve package.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: it's true nothing special, I just want to know by curiosity :)

Comment: It doesn't work because it's like if you would buy a chair in Ikea and instead of assembling it and then sitting, you would just sit on the box. `react-scripts` takes multiple parts that browsers can't understand and creates a bundle that can be understood by the browse and then serves it. `serve` just serves the files and the browser don't know what to do witht them

Comment: Ok i misunderstood the true purpose from serve package, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't built your `/build` folder with app bundle. It must be like this:

1. `npm start` - to run and edit code
2. `npm run build` - to build a bundle(creates/rebuild a `/build` folder)
3. `serve -s build` - serve/start the `/build` folder